# Express server has CORS enabled, though it still fails when performing aync HTTP request from Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, cross-domain

This is some weird problem we're having right now, and we need some help regarding the issue.

First of all, we've got an Express server that serves some data, acts as an API, and works pretty well when being consumed from the same domain. No problems here.

But we also want to use this API (since it's in our development server) from our computers, to leverage the data and test things easier and faster. Not a weird approach, right? Well, then we just set up CORS in the Express file. This is our API:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

const MockupData = require('./MockupData').MockupData;

// Setting up CORS and bodyparser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

// Mockup data setter
let mockupData;
const assignCollection = (requestedCollection) => {
    if(!mockupData || mockupData.collection != requestedCollection){
        mockupData = new MockupData(requestedCollection, false);
    }
}

const errorHandler = (err, res) => {
    console.error("ERR: ", err);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('error', { error: err });
}

// Router
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   assignCollection("achieved_combined");
    if(mockupData){
    mockupData.get(req.body)
        .then(data => res.send(data))
        .catch(err => errorHandler(err, res));
    }else{
        errorHandler(err, res);
    }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API responding");
})


app.listen(80, () => console.log("Pseudo-server listening to port 80"));
```

From Angular, this is the call:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataRequester{


    url = "http://our.subdomain.com";

    constructor(private http:Http){

    }


    /**
     * This method receives the "config" stateful object for setting up the 
     * conditions of the data that the app needs from the server. The data is 
     * returned in a promise that is fulfilled when the data is ready to be
     * consumed. 
     * @param config The config object with all the data.
     * @param reportTypes Types of reports to fetch. Options: cross_section, timeseries, panel
     * @returns The backend's response for the stated conditions.
     */
    requestData(config, reportTypes){
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            const query = this.buildQuery(config, reportTypes);

            this.http.post(this.url+"/api", query).subscribe( (response:any) => {
                if(response._body){
                    const data = JSON.parse(response._body);
                    console.log(data)
                    resolve(data);
                }
            }, err => this.errorHandler(err, reject));
        })
    }
```

But it keeps giving the same error over and over:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://webdev.objectiveportal.com/api. (Reason:
>   CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Why is it failing? Do you have any idea on why is this happening?

We would really appreciate some help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Express/CORS middleware. Install it first:
`npm install cors --save-prod`

Then, to enable access from all origins, no need to manually set headers. Just  add the following to your server's code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

For more details see https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: Yeah! We just tried this approach and worked perfectly. Thank you! :)